# Data Access using ASP.NET, what is the best?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-generation, data-access

I have been asking my self this question from the time i started workin in the software development field,

**What is the best way to access data?
Which gives the best performance?
Which is the best for maintainability?**

There are lots of solutions to deal with database in the Asp.Net web app,

1. Entity framework 4.0
2. Classes generator using ADO.Net such as [Code Author](http://www.codeauthor.org/) ( i liked the way it works and the way it accesses the database using the data access block in Microsoft Enterprise Library).

i will start a new project tomorrow,and i don't know which approach is better??Any idea?

Comment: the "best" is subjective, you should use the "best" tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Castle Active Record for data access in our new ASP.NET project. It's a great and easy tool that is built upon NHibernate. NHibernate itself is a great ORM for .Net.

Comment: I found the website of the Castle Active Record http://www.castleproject.org
but i don't know where to download the generator!

Also i would like to ask,,does it generate the CRUD stored procedures and the classes ,or should i do some manual work as i read in the get started section?

Comment: @Khaled: You just create your classes and inherit it from a specific base class then AR takes cares all things for you. getting started page: http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/index.html - download page: http://www.castleproject.org/castle/download.html - 
direct download link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/ActiveRecord/2.1/AR%202.1.1.zip/download -

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best".  There is only preference.  Some like MVC, some like [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/mvc), some like [Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata).  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx) works nicely, as does [LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)(although I hear that one is being deprecated, but I'm fuzzy on that.)  All work well.

Personally, I like WebForms, but if I want a quick and dirty CRUD app, I always opt for Dynamic Data, and if I need additional functionality mixed in, I can throw in some standard WebForm aspx pages.

Performance wise, I don't know that there's inherently a big difference.  All use the same code under the hood.  All are based on ADO.NET.  Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL seem to have additional overhead compared to the old-fashioned WebForms, but proper DB design and planning is probably of greater importance.